# Linked List HeadInsert

Tags: c++

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::insertAtHead(T item)
{
     ListItem<T> *node=new ListItem<T>(item);
     ListItem<T> *temp=head;
     if (temp==NULL)
     {                
         head=node;
     }
     else if (temp!=NULL)
     {
         node->next=temp;     
         temp->prev=node;
         head=node;
     }                                
 }
```

I am making a linked list using classes.ListItem is a struct which contains next and previous pointers and they are being pointed to NULL in the struct whenever a new node is made.ListItem has a value of datatype T which can be anything from int to string.I want to know if there are any loopholes in this code.It is basically an assignment of data structures and a test file has been given to us to test our code.But when I run that test file,it fails this piece of code.I just want a hint on whats wrong with this code.Thanks

Comment: What is it doing/not doing that you expect it to do?

Comment: "it fails" - How exactly does it fail? What problem are you dealing with? How did you try this piece of code?...

Comment: OT: Is your intention to have a *circular* linked list ?

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you have a `head` variable as a member variable in you `List` type

Also, from your `next`/`prev` references, I am assuming you have a doubly linked list:

```
ListItem<T> *temp = head;

if (temp != NULL) {
    temp->prev = node;
    head = node;
    node->prev = NULL;
    node->next = temp;
} else {
    head = node;
    node->prev = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;
}
```